# If I switch to Google's Cloud DNS from Namecheap to host the domain, do I get the great firewall in China?

Tags: networking, domain-name-system

I have a domain purchased via Namecheap, but now I might try Google's Cloud DNS to manage the domain.

However, Google is blocked in China (not sure about Namecheap, though). So I wonder if I move to Cloud DNS, my website gets blocked and/or too slow to access due to the great firewall.

Is it true? Or is it not relevant whether you use which DNS management service?

Comment: email china and ask them. :)  but not likely, different services/ports/domains

Answer (score 1):

I tried testing some `*.bc.googleusercontent.com` with [greatfirewallofchina.org](http://www.greatfirewallofchina.org/) and they weren't blocked at the moment. The fact that Google as a search provider is blocked doesn't necessarily mean all subnets owned by Google are.

That said, you can't count on that it stays that way, with any provider. The 金盾工程 can be considered hostile. (And now Serverfault may get blocked, too.)